# how to shuffle image without repetition stored in an array in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, uiimageview, nsarray

I have 10 images in viewcontroller and i want  to shuffle images at run time without repetition and want to apply touch event on those and find the tag of image which is touched

Comment: would it be safe to assume you have an nsmutablearray of 10 images or image views and you want to know how to randomly re-order the array?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess best bet would be put images in an Mutable Array and shuffle like this.
[Shuffling an array in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659718/shuffling-an-array-in-objective-c)

And add touch events in one of the ways mentioned here
[IOS: event when an Imageview is touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740375/ios-event-when-an-imageview-is-touched)

and trigger the view in your app to re-shuffle and re-draw the images on applicationDidBecomeActive or something like that.